# CSS - Giving border-radius to only sides

Tags: css

i am trying to copy a website it has a nav bar with buttons in side, those buttons only have border-radius to sides i tried giving border-radius but my buttons turned into horizontally oval shape

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#navigationBar {
background-color: #e4e4e4;
height: 40px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

</nav>
<nav id="navigationBar">
<button class="options">Islamic</button>
<button class="options">Educational</button>
<button class="options">Arts & Creative</button>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example contains no border radius at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using percentages for border-radius will cause this ugly oval shape. Set a pixel amount (12px here):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#navigationBar {
background-color: #e4e4e4;
padding: 10px;
}
.options{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 12px 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

</nav>
<nav id="navigationBar">
<button class="options">Islamic</button>
<button class="options">Educational</button>
<button class="options">Arts & Creative</button>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not this width & height ratio, but you can adjust it. Good idea is to merge style to css files.
With `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` and value which stands next to them you can modify the shape of the border.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#navigationBar {
background-color: #e4e4e4;
padding: 10px;
}
.options{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

</nav>
<nav id="navigationBar">
<button class="options">Islamic</button>
<button class="options">Educational</button>
<button class="options">Arts & Creative</button>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with border radius. In this case you can use:
`.options{ border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

giving 15px border-radius would work

```
.options {
   border-radius: 15px;
}
```